# problema al descargar excel generado desde java

Tags: java, excel, apache

tengo una aplicación web creada en java uso la librería Apache poi para generar un excel de una consulta, cuando ejecuto la aplicación desde el netbens se genera perfectamente el archivo excel, pero cuando despliego el war en el apache tomcat para ejecutarlo en el servidor e intento generar el excel no funciona.
que puede suceder?

la version java que estoy utilizando es java7 la version del apache poi 3.14

**Esta es la clase que ejecuta el proceso**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package modelo;

import Controlador.Informe;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

/**
 *
 * @author hp
 */
public class Informes extends conexion {

    List<Informe> listaf = new ArrayList<Informe>();

    public boolean aprovecha(String ini, String fin) throws SQLException, IOException {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String nit;
        int numRecibo;
        String inir = ini.replace("-", "");
        String finr = fin.replace("-", "");

        PreparedStatement consulta = con.prepareStatement("select DISTINCT nit_fuente from fuentes where activo = 'SI'");

        try {
            rs = consulta.executeQuery();
            String rutaArchivo = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/Suscriptores Aforados.xls";
            File archivoXLS = new File(rutaArchivo);
            if (archivoXLS.exists()) {
                archivoXLS.delete();
            }
            archivoXLS.createNewFile();
            Workbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook();
            FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(archivoXLS);
            Sheet hoja = libro.createSheet("Hoja 1");
            int f = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                nit = rs.getString("nit_fuente");
                ResultSet rsmate = null;

                PreparedStatement consultarecibo = con.prepareStatement("select clasematerial,tipoMaterial,nit_asociado,sum(cantidad) as total "
                        + "from ingresomaterial "
                        + "LEFT JOIN recibo on ingresomaterial.numRecibo = recibo.num_recibo "
                        + "WHERE nit_fuente ='"+nit+"' and FECHa BETWEEN '"+inir+"' and '"+finr+"' "
                        + "GROUP BY tipoMaterial ");
                rsmate = consultarecibo.executeQuery();
                System.out.println("modelo.Informes.aprovecha()" + consultarecibo);
                while (rsmate.next()) {

                    Informe lista = new Informe(nit, rsmate.getString("clasematerial"), rsmate.getString("tipoMaterial"),
                            rsmate.getString("total"), rsmate.getString("nit_asociado"));

                    listaf.add(lista);
                }

            }

            consruta(inir,finr);

            for (int x = 0; x < listaf.size(); x++) {
                //  System.out.println(listaf.get(x));
                Row fila = hoja.createRow(x);
                for (int c = 0; c < 5;) {
                    /*Creamos la celda a partir de la fila actual*/
                    Cell celda = fila.createCell(c);

                    if (x == 0) {
                        switch (c) {
                            case 0:
                                celda.setCellValue("Nit Fuente");
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                celda.setCellValue("Nit Asosicado");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                celda.setCellValue("Clase");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                celda.setCellValue("Total");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                celda.setCellValue("Total Toneladas ");

                                break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        /*Si no es la primera fila establecemos un valor*/

                        switch (c) {
                            case 0:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getNit());
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getNitSocio());
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getClase());
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                celda.setCellValue(listaf.get(x).getTipo());
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                double total = Double.parseDouble(listaf.get(x).getTotal());

                                celda.setCellValue(total);

                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    c++;
                }

            }

            libro.write(archivo);
            archivo.close();
         //   Desktop.getDesktop().open(archivoXLS);

            System.out.println("lista ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("error " + e);
            return false;
        }
        con.close();

        return true;
    }

    public void consruta(String inir, String finr) throws SQLException {

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement consulta = con.prepareStatement("select DISTINCT Cod_ruta from rutas");
        try {
        rs = consulta.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            String ruta = rs.getString("Cod_ruta");
            ResultSet rsmate = null;

                PreparedStatement consultarecibo = con.prepareStatement("select clasematerial,tipoMaterial,nit_asociado,sum(cantidad) as total "
                        + "from ingresomaterial "
                        + "LEFT JOIN recibo on ingresomaterial.numRecibo = recibo.num_recibo "
                        + "WHERE nit_fuente ='"+ruta+"' and FECHa BETWEEN '"+inir+"' and '"+finr+"' "
                        + "GROUP BY tipoMaterial ");
            rsmate = consultarecibo.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("modelo.Informes.aprovecha()" + consultarecibo);
            while (rsmate.next()) {

                Informe lista = new Informe(ruta, rsmate.getString("clasematerial"), rsmate.getString("tipoMaterial"),
                        rsmate.getString("total"), rsmate.getString("nit_asociado"));

                listaf.add(lista);
            }

        }

         } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el error que te dá? No queda claro si se trata de un error al generarlo, al almacenarlo en disco, al descargarlo...

Comment: no genera ningun error  la pagina queda en blanco no da la alarma que genera indicando que se descargo correctamente ni error solo queda en blanco.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy probable que sea un problema de rutas de directorios o permisos:

```
String rutaArchivo = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/Suscriptores Aforados.xls";
```

Puede que esta ruta exista y tengas permisos de escritura en tu entorno de desarrollo pero es probable que en el servidor no sea así.

Por tanto, verifica:

- La existencia de la ruta de directorios teniendo en cuenta ese "user.home" que puede variar según el usuario que ejecuta la aplicación web.
- Que dicho usuario tiene permisos de escritura en directorio directorio.

A parte de eso, te recomiendo encarecidamente que no uses espacios ni en los nombres de directorios ni en los nombres de archivos, sólo te pueden traer problemas.

Comment: no se si tenga que ver que sea una aplicación web, pero el usuario que ejecuta es el usuario administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Lo soluciones colocando una ruta absoluta independientemente si es disco C o D coloque

```
user= System.getProperty("user.name");
new File("/Users/"+user+"/Downloads/Certificaciones/Certificiación" + nombre + ".PDF")
```